# Firestore rules - allow by path

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I use Firebase's Firestore. I have a collection called "root" which has an item called "db".

I want to allow read and write access to everybody on exactly that item.

This is my Rule:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.path == 'root/db';
    }
  }
}
```

This rule was there by default, except this line `request.path == 'root/db';` which is my custom. I tried to set a timestamp rule and it works. But this by path does not work.

This is my request from the browser:

```
  const ref = doc(dbApi, "root", "db");
  console.log(ref.path);
  let db: Database;
  try {
    db = (await getDoc(ref)).data() as Database;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    throw err;
  }
```

`ref.path` logs `root/db` and `err` logs `FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

(Using "firebase": "9.6.4" javascript package in the app)

I've also tried some variations on this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage#path
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than use the catch all (`/{document=**}`) and then filter, just filter at the match statement instead:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /root/db {                <-- change it here
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

While this works, you should further restrict the rules to limit the shape of this document. If your database is all based on a single document, consider the RTDB instead as it provides finer grain controls over the data in the database.

Comment: Will this block all other operations on the DB except reads and writes to this document? For example the operation of getting all the documents from /root, or adding something else in root, or adding another collection?

Comment: @croraf All rules deny by default. When evaluating a rule, if it doesn't exist or throws an error (either due to missing documents or a syntax error), the operation will be blocked. A rule **must** evaluate to `true` before an operation is allowed. Because there is no wild card rule here, list operations should not be permitted, but you could change the rule to read `allow get, write: if true;` instead (`read` = `get, list`, `write` = `create, update, delete`).